# Pine Script strategy.close problem, cannot test strategy

Tags: pine-script

I was trying to test the strategy on pine in Trading View but receive this ERROR

Error: Cannot call `strategy.close` with arguments (literal__string, literal__integer, fun_call__operator <); available overloads: strategy.close(literal__string, series__bool) => void

the Strategy cannot be tested , anyone know what is the problem?

the script here:

---

```
ma_up = out1 >= out1[smoothe]
ma_down = out1 < out1[smoothe]

col = cc ? ma_up ? lime : ma_down ? red : aqua : aqua
col2 = cc2 ? ma_up ? lime : ma_down ? red : aqua : white

circleYPosition = out2

plot(out1, title="Multi-Timeframe Moving Avg", style=line, linewidth=4, color = col)
plot(doma2 and out2 ? out2 : na, title="2nd Multi-TimeFrame Moving Average", style=circles, 
linewidth=4, color=col2)
plot(sd and cross(out1, out2) ? circleYPosition : na,style=cross, linewidth=15, color=aqua)
//barcolor Plot for Price Crossing Moving Average #1
barcolor(spc and iscrossUp() ? (iscrossUp() ? yellow : na) : na)
barcolor(spc and iscrossDown() ? (iscrossDown() ? yellow : na) : na)
//barcolor Plot for Price Crossing Moving Average #2
barcolor(spc2 and iscrossUp2() ? (iscrossUp2() ? yellow : na) : na)
barcolor(spc2 and iscrossDown2() ? (iscrossDown2() ? yellow : na) : na)

plotchar(ma_up, char="B", text="BUY", location=location.belowbar)


strategy.entry ("butsell", true, qty=10, when=ma_up)
strategy.close ("butsell", qty=10, when=ma_down)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using v3 pine but using the arguments for v4 strategy.close()

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v3/#fun_strategy{dot}close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v3/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose)

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy{dot}close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose)